# Webpack.2.0 build error when passing CLI arguments

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have build script in package.json as

```
"clean-build": "rimraf build",
"prebuild": "npm run clean-build",
"build": "webpack --end.dev",
```

However I'm getting error on build task.

```
> webpack --end.dev

webpack 2.1.0-beta.21
Usage: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html
Usage without config file: webpack <entry> [<entry>] <output>
Usage with config file: webpack
```

Here is the entire [code](https://github.com/neginbasiri/webpack.git)

Do you know what am I missing in build task?

Thanks

Comment: You have `--end.dev` change it to `--env.dev`

Comment: Thanks for picking up this error. That fixed my build. If you write it done as answer I will accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `--end.dev` change it to `--env.dev`